# How is the json data in a transaction converted to a datastream internally?

Tags: smart-contract

I'm looking at datastream.hpp but it does not show how it creates a map or dictionary object as I would expect.

Also, does the 'fields' attribute in the .abi file affect what gets deserialised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different `datastream.hpp` headers, one for nodeos and one for contracts. It's unclear which you're asking about, so I'm including answers for both.

Nodeos's `datasteam.hpp` works with `raw.hpp` to [serialize maps here](https://github.com/EOSIO/fc/blob/f050d0cd0f81ff2e176548ffd34917a3b1f1f87b/include/fc/io/raw.hpp#L508) and [deserialize maps here](https://github.com/EOSIO/fc/blob/f050d0cd0f81ff2e176548ffd34917a3b1f1f87b/include/fc/io/raw.hpp#L519). Like iostreams, the code that reads or writes to a map expects the map is already constructed. `datastream.hpp` and `raw.hpp` don't use the ABI. [`abi_serializer`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/796511999b46063640396e9cd691a5262bab8207/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/abi_serializer.hpp) does use the ABI.

Contracts use eosiolib's `datasteam.hpp`. It [serializes maps here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/796511999b46063640396e9cd691a5262bab8207/contracts/eosiolib/datastream.hpp#L378) and [deserializes maps here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/796511999b46063640396e9cd691a5262bab8207/contracts/eosiolib/datastream.hpp#L387). Contracts don't use the ABI internally. The ABI describes the contract for other tools and libraries to consume.